# XAML/WP8 - How do I make Pivot Item Wider than 480px?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, pivotviewer

This is kind of an odd questions, however I have a pivot page with multiple pivot items.  And each pivot items has images that are larger than 480px in width.  What I'm seeing is that the images are being cropped off if they aren't originally showed on screen (you can see this when you scroll through the pages).

I don't want my images to be cropped; but I'm not sure how to make it work.  I've tried creating a grid that is wider than 480px hoping it won't crop what's in the grid, but it doesn't work great.  I've noticed it will crop one side but not another, and I'm not sure why.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: What about Panorama and wider item?

Comment: i don't think you can do that in a pivot control because pivot automatically adjust the width of pivotitem when it is greater than the widht of its viewport

Comment: I don't think it could be done in pivot.Use Panorama for image purposes.

Comment: Thanks.  I am playing with Panorama right now.  It is sad that pivotitem overrides my width.